# datepicker in fragment in android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, datepicker, android-view

I have this empty fragment and I want to create a datepicker but it says "Expression expected" on my fragment. Any help will do. Here is my code. Thank you.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_room, container, false);

    btn1 = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.btnfrom);

    mCurrentDate = Calendar.getInstance();

    day = mCurrentDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    month = mCurrentDate.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    year = mCurrentDate.get(Calendar.YEAR);

    btn1.setText("From..");

    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(RoomFragment, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                    monthOfYear = monthOfYear+1;
                    btn1.setText(monthOfYear+"/"+dayOfMonth+"/"+year);
                }
            }, year, month, day);
            datePickerDialog.show();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that you need to pass **RoomFragment.this** instead of **RoomFragment**.

```
DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(RoomFragment.this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                    monthOfYear = monthOfYear+1;
                    btn1.setText(monthOfYear+"/"+dayOfMonth+"/"+year);
                }
            }, year, month, day);
```

Let me know how it goes.

Comment: It says DatePickerDialog() in DatePickerDialog cannot be applied

Comment: instead of RoomFragment.this, did you try getContext()?

Comment: Thanks it worked tho. But I have two button and two datepicker, I also do the getContext() but it says Method call expected.

Comment: On the second one you are missing "new" on DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getContext()....)

Comment: Ow. I didn't notice that. Thank You @Sol